# UI-Router, I am trying to pass id in the url, but I keep getting nothing

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, state

I am trying pass id in the url so that it can be use by other page more specifically the detail page but i keep getting nothing. the url is going to the correct route but the id is not getting passed in. i have no idea what i'm doing wrong.

here my app.js file:

```
$stateProvider.state('contact', {

    url: '/contact',

    templateUrl: 'templates/contact.html',
    controller: 'mainController'

});

$stateProvider.state('contact.detail', {

    url: '/detail/:id',

    templateUrl: 'templates/contact.detail.html',
    controller: 'detailController'
});
```

and here is my controller file:

```
myApp.controller('detailController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 
  function ($scope, $stateParams) {

    'use strict';

    $scope.peoples = $scope.peoples[$stateParams.id];


}]);
```

and here is my contact file:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="person in peoples">
                    <td><a ui-sref="contact.detail({id: person.id})">{{person.firstname}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{person.lastname}}</td>
                    <td>{{person.age}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have values in `peoples` array when it reaches details controller? `$scope.peoples` ? Try doing an `alert( $stateParams.id)` in the details controller as first line.

Comment: Have you confirmed nothing gets passed to `$stateParams` - maybe do a `console.log($stateParams) in your controller and call the url directly as in `'http://localhost:.../detail/foo`?,

Answer (score 2):

There is a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/fBBXRbZNC6ZcCVjCdW0G?p=info)

One thing is:

> searching with indexer, e.g. `$scope.peoples[someIdValue]` will not find by ID but by position *(index)*

The second point would be:

> do not **re-assign** a reference **$scope.peoples** with new value *(and lose that reference)*

So, this should be the fix *(using **`lodash`** to find person)*

```
.controller('detailController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 
   function($scope, $stateParams) {

      //$scope.peoples = $scope.peoples[$stateParams.id];
      $scope.person = _.find($scope.peoples, {id: $stateParams.id});

  }])
```

Check that all in [action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fBBXRbZNC6ZcCVjCdW0G?p=info)